# Angular:- Event Misfire when Pointer Enters Sibling Control

Tags: angular

Requirements:

1. show images from the array
2. there is button at center of each image which should be shown on hover of image only.

So, as per requirements, I used ngFor loop to show the images and have button which got boolean true only when user enters the mouse on the image, it works fine but when I take pointer to button, both events are being fired :- mouse enter and mouse leave.

[image: Here is the image of console when I take pointer to the button]

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;" class='thumbnail'>
<div *ngFor="let gallery of galleries; let i = index ">

      <img 
        [src]="imagesrc "
        alt="gallery thumbnail" (mouseenter)="enter(i)" (mouseleave)="leave(i)"/>

   <button *ngIf='showEditButton' class="btn btn-primary" style="position:absolute;">EDIT</button>
  </div>


 public enter(i) {
    this.hoverIndex = i;
console.log('mouse enter');
   }

   public leave(i) {
    this.hoverIndex = null;
console.log('mouse leave');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to place the `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` events on the div (with the `*ngFor=""`) containing both the image and the button.

What I believe is happening is your mouse is leaving the `<img>` and entering the `<button>` thus firing the events.

I would also suggest you change the title of this post to something more appropriate:
`"Angular: Event Misfire when Pointer Enters Sibling Control"` for example.

Comment: Can I get stackblitz for that?

Comment: It didn't work because your `<img>` and `<button>` are represented in the DOM as **siblings** _and_ your events were on the img. Thus, when you hover over the `<button>`, the `<img>` is exited - firing the `(mouseleave)`, etc.